# Want List items vertical and inner list items horizontal Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollbar, flutter-listview, flutter-gridview

I want every `abcdLine`'s items `characters` in new line(vertically scrollable), and  all items of `characters` should be horizontally scrollable in flutter application. I tried with `Listview.builder()`, but I couldn't get what I want.

```
List abcdLine = [
{
'characters': ['Ka','Ka','Ki','Kee','Ku','Koo','Ke','Kai','Ko','Kau','Kam','Kah'],
},
{
'characters': ['Kha','Kha','Khi','Khee','Khu','Khoo','Khe','Khai','Kho','Khau','Kham','Khah'],
},
{
'characters': ['Ga','Ga','Gi','Gee','Gu','Goo','Ge','Gai','Go','Gau','Gam','Gah'],
},
],
```

What is better way?
Hope, I could clear.

I also tried using `GridView` and `ListView` but, that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ListView for Parent and for `characters` you can use `SingleChildScrolView(child:Row(....))` or You can ListView with fixedHeight, both case `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,`

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: ListView(
    children: [
      ...abcdLine.map((e) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          // you can ListView with horizontal direction with Fixed height
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              ...e['characters']?.map((e) {
                    return Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.primaries[
                          (e.length * 1000) % Colors.primaries.length],
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(e),
                    );
                  }).toList() ??
                  [],
            ],
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you looking for sliver list

Check out sliver list and sliver grid

[Sliver list](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverList-class.html)